# how to keep the variable order in ```cut ```order while using ```complete```

Tags: r, cut

I am using `cut` to generate subtotal of people count in age groups. The sample data and the codes are:

```
set.seed(12345)

#create a numeric variable Age       
AGE <- sample(0:110, 100, replace = TRUE)

Sample.data <-data.frame(AGE)

summary_data<- Sample.data %>% 
  group_by(grp =  cut(
    AGE,
    breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
    right=TRUE,
    labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)","Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
  )) %>% summarise(TotalPeople = n())
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

I would like to keep the age groups that doesn't have observation in the table. So I add complete and fill. I was able to fill 0 for the empty age groups, but the age groups's order also changed which I do not want it. See codes and results:

```
summary_data<- Sample.data %>% 
  group_by(grp =  cut(
    AGE,
    breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
    right=TRUE,
    labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)","Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
  )) %>% summarise(TotalPeople = n(),)%>% complete(grp = levels(grp), fill = list(TotalPeople = 0))
```

[image]

Is there a way to keep age groups in the order of cut order? Or is there a way to keep the age groups with 0 observation in another way so the age groups won't change its order?  The ideal results should looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `ordered_result = TRUE`. With `table` you can get the counts and with `as.data.frame`  you get a `data.frame` of the counts per group.

```
grp <- cut(Sample.data$AGE, breaks=c(-Inf, 0, 0.082, 2, 13, 18, 65, Inf)
 , ordered_result = TRUE
 , labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0 - 0.082] yrs","Infant (0.082-2] yrs",
    "Child (2-13] yrs", "Adolescent (13-18] yrs","Adult (18-65] yrs",
    "Elderly >65 yrs"))
as.data.frame(table(grp))
#                      grp Freq
#1            Foetus(0 yr)    1
#2 Neonate (0 - 0.082] yrs    0
#3    Infant (0.082-2] yrs    2
#4        Child (2-13] yrs   14
#5  Adolescent (13-18] yrs    5
#6       Adult (18-65] yrs   32
#7         Elderly >65 yrs   46
```

To get in addition the mean age you can use `xtabs`

```
x <- table(grp)
cbind(TotalPeople=x, meanAge=xtabs(AGE ~ grp, cbind(AGE, addNA(grp))) / x)
#                        TotalPeople   meanAge
#Foetus(0 yr)                      1  0.000000
#Neonate (0 - 0.082] yrs           0       NaN
#Infant (0.082-2] yrs              2  1.500000
#Child (2-13] yrs                 14  9.071429
#Adolescent (13-18] yrs            5 15.000000
#Adult (18-65] yrs                32 41.093750
#Elderly >65 yrs                  46 87.434783
```

Or you can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(AGE ~ grp, cbind(AGE, addNA(grp)), function(x) 
 c(TotalPeople=length(x), meanAge=mean(x)), drop=FALSE)
#                      grp AGE.TotalPeople AGE.meanAge
#1            Foetus(0 yr)        1.000000    0.000000
#2 Neonate (0 - 0.082] yrs              NA          NA
#3    Infant (0.082-2] yrs        2.000000    1.500000
#4        Child (2-13] yrs       14.000000    9.071429
#5  Adolescent (13-18] yrs        5.000000   15.000000
#6       Adult (18-65] yrs       32.000000   41.093750
#7         Elderly >65 yrs       46.000000   87.434783
```

or you can use `by`

```
by(AGE, grp, function(x) c(TotalPeople=length(x), meanAge=mean(x)))
#grp: Foetus(0 yr)
#TotalPeople     meanAge 
#          1           0 
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#grp: Neonate (0 - 0.082] yrs
#NULL
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#grp: Infant (0.082-2] yrs
#TotalPeople     meanAge 
#        2.0         1.5 
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#grp: Child (2-13] yrs
#TotalPeople     meanAge 
#  14.000000    9.071429 
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#grp: Adolescent (13-18] yrs
#TotalPeople     meanAge 
#          5          15 
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#grp: Adult (18-65] yrs
#TotalPeople     meanAge 
#   32.00000    41.09375 
#------------------------------------------------------------ 
#grp: Elderly >65 yrs
#TotalPeople     meanAge 
#   46.00000    87.43478
```

Comment: Your are correct! What should I do if I also want to get the average age in each group? how should I change table set up for that? Many thanks.

Comment: Therefore you can use `xtabs`, but then you will see that your `breaks` do not fit the `labels`.

Comment: Other options are e.g. `aggregate` or `by`.

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent dropping the groups by adding `.drop = FALSE` to `group_by`:

```r
library(dplyr)
set.seed(12345)

#create a numeric variable Age       
AGE <- sample(0:110, 100, replace = TRUE)

Sample.data <-data.frame(AGE)

summary_data<- Sample.data %>% 
  group_by(grp =  cut(
    AGE,
    breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
    right=TRUE,
    labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)","Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
  ), .drop = FALSE) %>% summarise(TotalPeople = n())
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
summary_data
#> # A tibble: 7 x 2
#>   grp                        TotalPeople
#>   <fct>                            <int>
#> 1 Foetus(0 yr)                         1
#> 2 Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)           0
#> 3 Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)              0
#> 4 Child(2-12.999 yrs)                  2
#> 5 Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)           14
#> 6 Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)               37
#> 7 Elderly(65-199 yrs)                 46
```